# Prevent PasteSpecial Command from Pasting the Values and merging columns automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy one excel column data into another excel by using PasteSpecial function of VBA and I can able to copy the data but when there is no data in the destination right column PasteSpecial making the columns merged.[image: Please see the image how the 'pastespecial' Pasted the data]

DestSheet.Range(ColumnLetter & LastRowDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: the structure of the state of the data sheet (how it was merged),
It seems to be necessary to know the state of the sheet (whether or not it is merged) by pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the destination cells are not merged. PasteSpecial inherently does not merge cells, so I think it might be an issue with the destination cells being already merged. In general, if the structure of merged cells is different, pasting only the value causes an error.

Comment: In the destination file First Five cells were merged in the same column

Comment: I edited your answer by mistake. Please revise your answer.